# mixing a little dish soap and water into your compound

Tags: drywall

I was reading a tread about how little air holes appear in drywall mud. There were multiple suggestions of adding a little ivory soap and water to drywall mud to make it as smooth as a baby's butt. How much soap to water to mud would all you pros out there recommend?

Comment: soap reduces the surface tension of water ... soap allows water to flow into smaller spaces

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since is did it but it did have an impact on the air bubbles.

How much soap ? Very little, much less than you think.

I have done the soap, maybe a half tablespoon for a gallon or two of mud, but i do not use any water.

I remember adding too much the first time and it was a little thin/loose, hard to work with.

I used generic dish soap.

You can always add more but you can not take it out. ( *I have cut this board twice and it is still too short* )

Comment: c/two/too/ unless you intended that as an "error within the error".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact   i hit the post button 2 quick, ;) should have proof read. Two, To, Too, 2

Comment: Times like these make me feel 50% better than my peers: I cut it 3 times and it was still too short!

Comment: I don't understand, once you realize it is too short why wouldn't you cut the other side?

Answer (score 0):

The issues with air holes is mainly when you are using the premix joint compound.

What my crew does is:

- start with empty bucket (left over).
- Scoop in about 1/3 of a new buck of joint compound.
- add joint compound powder
- add water (of course)
- add a squirt of dawn (for bucket - about as much as you would use to wash your hands after you work on a car)
- the mix should come out less thick than peanut butter or Nutella
- the key is the mixing it hard with a good mixing paddle on an old drill.

If you are going to use premix good luck mixing it in the bucket it comes in.  It for sure needs a bit of water and a dab of soap but you probably won't have the power to mix it or the space.   You will need to mix a little at a time with just a tiny bit of soap and maybe 1/2" cup water to gallon.   (if you put too much water in, add more compound)